# is there a way to sign a string wth SHA1withRSA in dart?

Tags: dart, cryptography, sign

Hello I am cosidering using dart for a project, but have a requirement where I need to be able to create a digest by signing a string with a key using SHA1withRSA.

So far the official crypto library in dart does not seem to support RSA encryption.  There are other libraries but with very limited documentation.

Comment: Does it have to be SHA1? SHA1 got broken in 2017 and is considered generally unsafe. Why not use SHA256?

Comment: I totally agree with you, but sadly it is not my choice. A lot of govts and legacy system still use it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. That seems to be the very reason that RSA with SHA1 has relatively little support in Dart since the Dart community didn't truly take off until early 2018. From what I can find, the [pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) package (a port from the Java BouncyCastle library) seems to be your best bet - while it's unfortunately no longer actively supported, it's high popularity suggests that it is still usable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a closer look at the pointycastle package.